# Can class of linux device be NULL?

Tags: linux-device-driver

Can I pass NULL pointer to the first argument of [device_create](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/include/linux/device.h#L583) function?

I'm using device_create() to create character device file in sysfs. This file don't represent any physical device (it is used to provide an access to a set of devices connected to various buses). What class should I use with device_create() to create such a file?

Comment: Sorry, Before posting my answer, I did not notice that the question is quite old. You have probably already solved the problem by now.

Comment: That's not a reason for not posting an answer. I've used newly created class, but that might be inconvenient for those, who'll read answers later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own `struct class` to put the devices under. For example:

```
your_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "your-fake-devices");
```

You'll then be able to find any devices you create as `/sys/class/your-fake-devices/device-name/`

Answer (score 0):

An error code (`-ENODEV` currently) will be returned if you attempt to use `NULL` for the `class` parameter.